# How to have img with text in it fill <img> container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a title image to my website in the top left and have a png loaded in but i cant get it to match the img size and if i resize it to much it messes up the spacing on the website, is there any work around to this or should i be using something other than an ? Thank you in advance, here is the picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want your image which has text inside of it to fill your container?
If that is the case create a `<div class="container"></div>` and put your `img` inside it.

Example:

```
<div class="container>
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

In your css give the container a width and your image a width of `width: 100%`

Answer (score 1):

you could have your text in one container and then set a bckground image for that container using the image you want

```
<div class="bg-logo">Your text here</div>
```

and then in css

```
.bg-logo{
background-image: url(..your url here) no-repeat contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<img style="object-fit:fill">
```

Other values for object-fit are "cover" and "contain"

So see which works for you